# ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions on onehotencoder

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to use onehotencoder to transform my categorical data, however, i'm stuck at this step :

X = transformer.fit_transform(X)

I'm not sure what I missed but i'm less familiar with python and I appreciate anyone who are willing to help, thanks!

Here is the data set :
[Data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoQXN.png)

I'm trying to transform the country column

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#import dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,3].values

#Taking care of Missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer  
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])

#Encoding Categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

transformer = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])],
                                 remainder='passthrough')
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
#X = np.array(transformer.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)
```

and here is the error :

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

Comment: Hey @potatoCatz, did you get a solution for this? I have the same error with my code while using OneHotEncoder.fit_transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you csv file, if it looks exactly like this:

```
Country,Age,Salary,Purchased    
France,44,72000,No    
Spain,27,48000,Yes    
Germany,30,54000,No    
Spain,38,61000,No    
Germany,40,nan,Yes    
France,35,58000,Yes    
Spain,nan,52000,No    
France,48,79000,Yes
Germany,50,83000,No
France,37,67000,Yes
```

I ran your code and I didn't get any error, despite some warnings from sklearn